# generic programming with polymorphism and generic vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, polymorphism, generic-programming

I have this code:

```
struct All { public: All() {} ~All() {} };

template <typename T>
struct any : public All
{
    public:
        any() : All() {}
        ~any() {} 
        T value;
};

int main()
{
    any<int>* a = new any<int>;
    a->value = 55;

    any<string>* b = new any<string>;
    b->value = "Hello World !";

    vector<All*> vec;
    vec.push_back(a);
    vec.push_back(b);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)vec.size(); i++) {
        All* tmp = vec[i];
        cout << tmp->value << endl; // Error appears here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the following error:

> struct 'All' has no member named 'value'

And i don't know how to avoid this error. It seems that in the for loop `tmp` is a All object, and All objects has no member named value. 
They have no ways to access to child struct (`any`) member variable from the All object `tmp` to avoid this problem and have a fully fonctionnal generic vector ?

Comment: You could add a `print` virtual function to `All` and `any<T>`, and call it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the base / derived class are not polymorphic `-> value` can't be accessed using base pointer type.

You can add a virtual function to print the value.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct All
{
public: All() {} ~All() {}
        virtual void print() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct any : public All
{
public:
    any() : All() {}
    ~any() {}
    T value;

    virtual void print() override
    {
        cout << value << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
        auto a = std::make_shared<any<int>>();
a->value = 55;

auto b = std::make_shared<any<string>>();
b->value = "Hello World !";

vector<std::shared_ptr<All>> vec;
vec.push_back(a);
vec.push_back(b);

for (auto const& elem : vec)
{
    elem->print();
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but i don't want to print the value to the standard output. I want to `print()` to return the value of `any::value`. But i can't do it, because this will make a trouble when making the declaration of `any::print()`in `All` because i don't know the return type in the declaration of it. Help me !

Comment: then delete the base class, and just use "any" class with template type T